# is the expression "do the needful" acceptable to native English speakers?

Tags: grammar

A professor of English from English and foreign language university corrected "do the needful" as "do what is necessary. some others say "do what needs to be done"
I hope the native speakers of English will respond to my question and talk about the acceptability of all these expressions

Edit: it is not a duplicate because I wanted to know whether the expression is acceptable to native speakers.I did not ask why such an expression is asked instead of a question

Comment: The comments below the question should have been retained.

Comment: I think this is the perfect answer for its simplicity and being factually correct: [*British native speakers would normally say ‘Please do whatever is necessary’ instead of ‘Please do the needful’ (although ‘needful’ has been used as a noun since the fourteenth century)*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/43610/44619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interesting comments show this question to be a great example of regional differences in English usage. Generally speaking, a variant from one region won't have relevance to equivalent expressions from other regions. I have NOT heard "do the needful" as standard US English. However, television has popularized the expressions "just do it" and "make it so," which are probably equivalent.